# Modify PHP Object Property Name

Tags: php, object, properties

In PHP is it possible to change an Objects property key/name? For example:

```
stdClass Object
(
     [cpus] => 2
     [created_at] => 2011-05-23T01:28:29-07:00
     [memory] => 256
)
```

I wish to change the key `created_at` to `created` in the Object leaving an object that looks like:

```
stdClass Object
(
     [cpus] => 2
     [created] => 2011-05-23T01:28:29-07:00
     [memory] => 256
)
```

Answer (score 21):

```
$object->created = $object->created_at;
unset($object->created_at);
```

Something like an adapter class may be a more robust choice though, depending on where and how often this operation is necessary.

```
class PC {
    public $cpus;
    public $created;
    public $memory;

    public function __construct($obj) {
        $this->cpus    = $obj->cpu;
        $this->created = $obj->created_at;
        $this->memory  = $obj->memory;
    }
}

$object = new PC($object);
```

Answer (score 7):

No, since the key is a reference to the value, and not a value itself.
You're best off copying the original, then removing it.

```
$obj->created = $obj->created_at;
unset(obj->created_at);
```

Comment: The "No" should be actually a "Yes"! You give the wrong answer, but provide **the** right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Its similar to @deceze adapter, but without the need to create an extra class

```
$object = (object) array(
  'cpus'    => $obj->cpus,
  'created' => $obj->created_at,
  'memory'  => $obj->memory
);
```